# WPF. Get the value of the attached property from XAML, without object instantiation

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have some user control with attached property, e. g. Grid.Column. Usually, to get the value of the attached property, I need an instance of dependency object.

Is there any way to get the value in code without instantiation of object?

Comment: without instantiating which object? the question is not clear

Comment: Object which the property is attached to.

Comment: @Dennis do you want to get the default value of an attached property??

Comment: @Markus, I want to get **initial** value of attached property in **concrete** markup (and this markup is corresponding to some user control). See comment to Pavlo's answer below.

Comment: @Dennis, I still don't really get it. Can you give us some background information as to why you want to do that? you already got 3 people on your problem, maybe someone can tell you how to solve your bigger problem more easily.

Comment: @Markus, I've posted more wide explanation below. I'm considering attached property value as the way of finding correspondence between the view model and the view.

Answer (score 0):

In case of XAML like this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition/>
       <ColumnDefinition/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   ...
   <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Grid.Column="1" .../>
</Grid>
```

It is possible to get a value of the attached property like this:

```
var textBoxColumn = Grid.GetColumn(MyTextBox);
```

`Grid.GetColumn` is a static method, so you don't need a reference to the object that defines this property, but you do need a reference to the object to which the property is attached.

Comment: @Dennis - Yes, that is what I said. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Pavlo - sorry for prev. comment. The question is how to do that without object reference. In markup you've posted, **initial** value of Grid.Column will be the same for all instances of control. So, markup can be treated as a **static** information. And if it is static, why the instance of object is necessary?

Comment: @Dennis - Instance IS necessary because the property value is stored with the object the same way as regular CLR property value is stored in the instance field of an object.

Comment: @Pavlo, yes, I know about the value storage... But XAML, in fact, is a resource. I've supposed, may be there's a way to load markup, corresponding to user control type and parse it?

Comment: @Dennis - this is really strange requirement... If you do need to do so, you can always load XAML as usual XML and parse it.

Comment: @Pavlo, not so strange. :) I have a set of views (user controls), and a set of view models. Each view model can have zero or more views. I want to set the correspondence between view model and  view in view's markup via attached property. On application startup, I have a set of view **types**, not instances. When I need to show view model, I want to get all its views => I have to filter set of view types and instantiate only types, that matching condition. Yes, I know, one the solution is to use attribute... but it is not desirable to modify codebehind for some reasons.

Comment: @Dennis - Don't invent the wheel - use existing MVVM framework for this. For example Caliburn.Micro: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/. At least take a look at how it is done there.

Comment: @Pavlo, "To do this, **CM uses a simple naming pattern** to find a UserControl". Oh, no... ) I'll better use an attribute.

Comment: @Dennis - This is only one of the options out there. You can also look into Prism+MEF (where the composition is done using attributes).

Comment: @Pavlo, I use ideas from Prism and MVVMLight as a basis... But like any open source, they are concepts and must be complete before use them in real projects.

Comment: @Dennis Prism is a microsoft recommendation that is pretty mature! We use it in BIG real projects...